# Libgdx - Hiero tool create mirrored font

Tags: android, libgdx

i try to use Hiero tool ( v2.0 ) to build a font for my Android - libgdx game, but it always produces a mirrored font :((. Could you help me, pls?

PS: I run Hiero v 2.0 on win7, and when I turn it off, it always ends by "Unresponsive Program" error :).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is well know bug http://cocos2d-central.com/topic/259-problem-with-hiero-font-creator/

Try to flip the image horizontally using image editor software like Gimp